# Предложения с прилагательным в препозиции

Tags: синтаксис

Вот примеры предложений, которые часто встречаются в комментариях или отзывах:

> Хорошая песня! Классное выступление! Виртуозный музыкант! Выдающееся произведение!

Какой это тип предложения? По моему мнению, эти предложения не являются назывными, потому что здесь нет бытийности, есть только оценочное суждение. Остается два варианта: либо это двусоставное предложение с инверсией, либо неполное предложение с пропущенным подлежащим (объект, который мы характеризуем) (вариант, что здесь неполное предложение, мне также кажется маловероятным). К какому типу предложений Вы бы отнесли подобные конструкции?

P.S. Если я ошибаюсь, и эти случаи можно трактовать как назывные предложения, приведите, пожалуйста, подтверждающие примеры из источников.

Comment: >> *либо неполное предложение с пропущенным подлежащим* – а поподробнее можно? Вставьте во фразу это "пропущенное подлежащее".

Comment: В некоторых случаях можно вставить "это": (Это) классная песня! (Проводить аналогию между языками, может быть, нехорошо, но все же: Good song! - This is a good song!)

Comment: Почему в некоторых? В любое номинативное можно вставить "это". Это унылая пора! С точки зрения грамматики не придерешься.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, этот вид предложений можно отнести к  постпозитивным номинативным предложениям оценочного характера.

Среди номинативных предложений выделяется особая группа – постпозитивные номинативы разного вида, в частности они могут иметь значение оценки.

Валгина Н.С  Синтаксис современного русского языка

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-025.htm

Номинатив в постпозиции может заключать в себе значение оценки: Есть письмо. На листке – торопливые строки: «Если можешь – прости. Так случилось. Ушла». **Равнодушные строки. Слова ледяные** (Лис.);

Номинативы со значением оценки и обобщения сближаются своей предицирующей (сказуемостной) функцией по отношению к **предшествующему** высказыванию.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ваш ответ очень полезен. Только Валгина Н.С. не относит такие постпозитивные номинативы к номинативным предложениям.

Comment: Валгина не относит, но проблема-то существует. Всё зависит от определения. Есть чисто бытийные номинативные предложения, которые обозначают существование предмета и его наличие в поле зрения наблюдателя (Гостиная.)   Есть событийные назывные предложения (Зима. Война).Эти предложения содержат элемент протяженности во времени, а это уже не чистая номинация. Есть оценочно-бытийные предложения: Красота! Это тоже не номинация в чистом виде.

Comment: Получается, что предложения одинаковой структуры могут иметь разные оттенки значений, наверное, их следует изучать в одной теме и они должны иметь какое-то общее определение. Например: Богатый дом. 1) Ремарка в пьесе, указание места действия. 2) Именительный темы (препозиция),  далее идут рассуждения автора на эту тему. 3) Оценка, постпозитивное определение следует после описания дома.